# Flask BackgroundScheduler running in multiple workers

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have the following code

```
INTERVAL = 30  # in seconds
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(
    executors={'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(1)})
scheduler.start()
scheduler.add_job(
    func=import_from_folder,
    trigger=IntervalTrigger(seconds=INTERVAL),
    id='importer_job',
    name='Importer',
    replace_existing=True)

# Shut down the scheduler when exiting the app
atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())
```

My app has 4 workers, which makes the above Scheduler run 4 times.
Is there a way to force the Scheduler to run only in 1 worker ?? or to verify if the scheduler id is already runing in another worker ?